# EJB Timer goes off before scheduled time

Tags: timer

I'm creating a timer using javax.ejb.TimerService to start at a specific date and time, and thereafter expire periodically.

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

Date startDateTime = null;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");
DateTime time = formatter.parseDateTime(ConfigProperties.getProperty("timer.starttime"));
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().withTime(time.getHourOfDay(), time.getMinuteOfHour(), 0, 0);
startDateTime = dateTime.toDate();

long timerIntervalMs = Long.valueOf(ConfigProperties.getProperty("timer.interval.mins")) * 60 * 1000;
timerService.createTimer(startDateTime, timerIntervalMs, null);
```

The above initialization code is executed when my server boots up. However the timer expires while the server is still booting up (**before** startDateTime has been reached). Why is this happening? I'm trying this out on my local machine and startDateTime is initialized to a future time according to my local system clock.

After this first incorrect expiration, it works perfectly fine - expires at startDateTime and thereafter every `timerIntervalMs` ms.

I checked the documentation but didn't find anything pertinent to my problem -
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createTimer(java.util.Date, long, java.io.Serializable)

Comment: I suppose startDateTime > now + 1 minute, right? What appserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using Jboss 4.2.3, EJB 3.0. Yes, startDateTime is around 5 mins in the future.

Comment: this is also obvious, of course, but I have to check, startDateTime IS now + 5 minutes, you're not assuming that createTimer(startDateTime, 300000, null) means startDateTime + 5 minutes, but a timer that will start at startDateTime and then will repeat every 5 minutes after that, right?

Comment: I expect timer to go off at startDateTime, which is now+5mins, and thereafter it should go off every 5 mins (300000ms).

Comment: Great. Now, could you post your code where startDateTime is declared?

Comment: Edited my question and added the code. Thanks for following up.